# recursion repeats output - python 3

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying out recursion and am having trouble

Here's the code:

```
inputs = []
def ins(x,y,length):
    global inputs, j
    if [x,y] not in inputs:
        inputs.append([x,y])
    if x is not length:
        ins(x+1,y,length)
    if y is not length:
        ins(x,y+1,length)
j = 0
ins(0,0,12)
```

but it seems to go over the same x,y combo multiple times and gives an inputs ends up being 10400599 items long instead of just 169

Comment: Try replacing `is not` with `!=`

Comment: no repro - this works without changes in Py2.7 and [Py3](https://repl.it/repls/CurlyGrossComputing)

Comment: Works in python 3.6 too

Comment: yes it works, but it takes longer than it should and repeats x,y combos resulting in really long inputs instead of fairly short inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad all i had to do was change:

```
if y is not length:
```

to:

```
elif y is not length:
```